# Length of a root string - proof clarification

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

I am trying to understand the proof In Fulton's and Harris's *Representation Theory* book where they show that the length of the root is at most 4:

**Theorem** If $\alpha,\beta$ are roots with $\beta \neq \pm \alpha$, then the $\alpha$ string through $\beta$, i.e. the roots of the form 
\begin{equation*}
\beta - p\alpha, \beta -(p-1)\alpha, \dots, \beta - \alpha, \beta, \beta + \alpha, \beta + 2\alpha, \dots, \beta + q\alpha 
\end{equation*}
has at most four in a string, i.e. $p+q \leq 3$; in addition, $p-q=n_{\beta\alpha}$

where $n_{\beta \alpha}= 2\frac{(\beta,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}$ (positive definite form on a vector space $V$) and then the reflection of a root $\beta$ in the hyperplane orthogonal to a root $\alpha$ is given by 
\begin{equation*}
W_{\alpha}(\beta) = \beta - n_{\beta \alpha}\alpha
\end{equation*}

They first proof the second part, that is: $p-q=n_{\beta\alpha}$. Then to prove the first part they say: take $p=0$, and then $q=-n_{\beta\alpha}$, which we know is an integer no larger that 3 (a root system here is assumed to be crystallographic) and that's it. I feel really stupid, but I don't understand why is it sufficient to consider the case where $p=0$. Say, $p=1$ then $1=n_{\beta\alpha}+q$. Say $n_{\beta\alpha}=-3$ (am I making a mistake here, considering such case?) then $q=4$ and $p+q=5>3$. What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $\beta$ by $\beta' := \beta-p\alpha$. Notice that the $\alpha$-strings through $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are identical sets, in particular have the same length.

You can also check (using linearity of $W_\alpha$ and the definite form $(\cdot , \cdot )$, as well as $W_\alpha(\alpha) =-\alpha$) that once you have the assertion about $W_\alpha$ for $\beta'$, you get it for $\beta$, because e.g. $n_{\beta \alpha} = n_{\beta' \alpha} +2p$, and everything stays consistent.

As to your proposed counterexample: It follows from this theorem that assuming $n_{\beta \alpha} = -3$ *enforces*, for the reason you outlined, that $p=0$, which case happens exactly iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ form a basis of a root system of type $G_2$, as [seen here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Root-system-G2.png).

Comment: Thanks! Let me make sure I understand this. So basically I want to show that if $\alpha$ root string through $\beta'$ has at most 4 in string then $\alpha$ through $\beta$ has at most 4 in string. But then we can consider $\alpha$ root string through $\beta'$: $(\beta -p\alpha) -k\alpha,\dots,(\beta -p\alpha) +l\alpha$. But then we can take $k=0 $ so that root string has at most 4 in the string (since -$n_{\beta'\alpha} = l$) and so then by the result we showed at the start we deduce that $\alpha$ root string through $\beta$ also has at most 4 in the string. Is that a correct logic?

Comment: I'd say we *must* have $k=0$ because otherwise, the root string through $\beta$ would not start at $\beta-p\alpha$ but at $\beta-(p+k)\alpha$. Similarly, necessarily $l= q+p$. And then yes, by the proven result, $l =-n_{\beta'\alpha} \le 3$.

Comment: and then since we have shown that if root string through $\beta'$ has at most 4 then so does root string through $\beta$ we get that $p+q \leq 3$, as required?

Comment: Yes. ----------